# Hosting my WordPress site out of a subdirectory

Tags: directory, hosting

I'm currently hosting several WordPress sites on one host account with cPanel, each site with its own domain. Right now, each of my domains maps to a subdirectory on the server, except for the primary domain, which by default maps to the public_html directory directly.

Because of this, in my public_html folder, I have my primary domain's WP files mixed in with the add-on domain root folders, thus becoming a little confusing. I'd like to put my primary site's WP files into its own folder and host from that folder.

With add-on domains, I know I can select the folder to which they refer to, but I'm not familiar with how to change where the primary domain directs as its root directory.

Or is there a better way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress have a Codex entry just for you: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Answer (score 1):

in New cPanel it should create a folder for each add-on domains in root folder (not public_html folder) maybe your cPanel is older version. To overcome your problem first option is to update your cPanel and second option is using WordPress general settings > WP Installation Directory and WordPress URL.